# How do I make html have priority over firefox's memory for select elements?

Tags: html, firefox

Consider the following piece of code :

```
<select>
    <option value="0">foo</option>
    <option value="1" selected="selected">bar</option>
</select>
```

If I select the first option and reload the page, the first option stays selected and the select does not switch to the second option. How can I force firefox to give priority to the html?

Comment: Strange, I remember that Firefox does this, but I can not reproduce this behaviour on my PC, I have Firefox 3.5.9 on Ubuntu 9.10.

Comment: I'm running Firefox 3.6.3 on Lucid Lynx, but I have been observing this behavior for a long time on many sites with many other form fields (radio and checkboxes have the same behavior I think)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good question. I think this can't be done using pure HTML.

You could try using JavaScript to reset the form. I don't know what it will reset to, but I guess it will do what you want:

```
 document.forms["formname"].reset();
```

needs to be triggered on the `load` event of course (or in `ready()` in jQuery).

Comment: Thank you, this works : a full jQuery solution : jQuery("#pwet").each(function(){this.reset();});

Comment: @greg0ire, your code implies that you have multiple `#pwet` defined.. IDs should be unique .. if you have only one, you could use the more efficient `jQuery("#pwet")[0].reset();`.. but i am just nit-picking :)

Comment: I do not have multiple pwet defined, but this piece of code wouldn't work : jQuery("#pwet").reset(), I don't know why . I found the workaround on this page : http://simple.procoding.net/2008/11/22/how-to-reset-form-with-jquery/ Your solution works great and is more efficient, so +1
BTW, this topic is all about nit-picking so feel free to do so!

Answer (score 2):

Select the second option using Javascript on page load.

Answer (score 1):

When you load your page the `selected="selected"` will say which option to highlight in the select so that should work... for the first time :D.

To reload the page you must click in the browser address bar and then hit enter or type CTRL+SHIFT+R.

If I remember correctly it has something to do with caching. Firefox will remember the values of the form elements and use those instead of doing a complete refresh which is useful if you've filled out half the form and don't want to be forced to start over again on a refresh.

However it creates other problems as you have seen. The [following page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/how_to_turn_off_form_autocompletion) describes some ways of handling this issue.

Comment: -1 As I said, it has to do with Firefox's memory (concerning forms), not cache. And I'm not going to hack every visitor's machine to press Ctrl+Shift+R... but thanks for answering anyway

Answer (score 1):

I've had this problem and my solution was using PHP to give each name a random 5 digit key, it stops firefox remembering parts of forms. for example:

```
<input type="text" name="35472username"></input>
<input type="password" name="56784password"></input>
```

then when processing the form i would `substr()` the name.

It works well but there may be more efficient methods

Comment: Nice solution, but incompatible with caching, and it requires additional code to filter out the random digit key if you want to find your data...